# Can two SSDs run slower than one?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance

I'm planning to buy a new SSD to add to my current config so that I can finally stop barely squeezing one game at a time on the same SSD as my OS (currently I have a 120GB one) and it got me wondering - may doing that hit the performance in games?

Currently the game resides on the same storage device as the OS, in case of adding a second SSD they would be sitting on a different one - would they still be running as fast as if they were being played from the same drive as the OS, then?

I suspect the access time cost (if any) from one SSD to the other would be negligible but still I figured it's better to ask first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be faster because the SSD will see less load.

I don't understand your reasoning for why you think it would be slower.  It doesn't make any sense. There is no "from one SSD to the other", there will just be accesses to both SSDs.